# Python Regex Logic for matching IP Addresses

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Can some one explain to me why this is not matching and i am receiving the Unacceptable.

```
linesout = "test.host.com (10.200.100.10)"
pat = re.compile("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")
test = pat.match(linesout)
if test:
        print "Acceptable ip address"
else:
        print "Unacceptable ip address"
```

Thank you

Comment: `re.match` is from the start of the string, you're looking for `re.search`.

Comment: Also note that `999.999.999.999` is most definitely not an acceptable IP address, although your code would claim that it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `search` in place of `match`

```
pat = re.compile("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")
test = pat.search(linesout)
```

If you want to use `match` then prepend regex with `.*`

```
pat = re.compile(".*\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")
test = pat.match(linesout)
```

Output in both case:

```
Acceptable ip address
```

Quoting from documentation  of [search() vs. match()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of
>   the string, while re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the
>   string (this is what Perl does by default).

Comment: Ah yes I see the difference now as well as how I can use match. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: @CDubya Your regex is better written as `(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}`

Answer (score -1):

```
pat = re.compile("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
test = pat.match(hostIP)
if test:
   print ("Acceptable ip address")
else:
   print ("Unacceptable ip address")
```